# How to aim a gun where the camera is pointing?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a fixed "Over-The-Shoulder" camera system, and i want to aim the gun where the camera is pointing at.

My best bet was to use the `CFrame.Rotation`, but it didn't work so well.

That's when i tried, getting the angles from the camera every time it changed, using: `workspace.CurrentCamera.Change:Connect`, and then applying the rotation vectors *(`Camera.CFrame.Rotation`)* to the entire of the player's body.

Then i've tried implementing Inverse Kinematics, to my code, but honestly, i could not stand copied code that i don't know how it works, so i scraped everything that i've copied.

Everything that i found about IK *(Inverse Kinematics)*, was little to no useful, since no one really did what i want to achieve.

I don't know if it's achievable or not, *but*, if it helps, here is the state of my code, and an [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffh68.jpg).

```lua
-- Script for controling the player camera.
-- Used for aiming in general.

-- Game global table
local globals = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.globalStates)

-- Normal services
local UserInputService, runService = game:GetService("UserInputService"), game:GetService("RunService")
local LocalPlayer =  game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer -- Get client's player
local Camera = game:GetService("Workspace").CurrentCamera -- Player's camera(?)
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService") 

local PlayerMouse = LocalPlayer:GetMouse()

local DEF_FOV = 70
local AIM_FOV = 35
local AIM_SENS = 0.3
local AIM_DURR_TIME = 0.15

local xAngle, yAngle = 0, 0
local cameraOffset = Vector3.new(3.5, 0, 7.5)

local tweenIn = TweenService:Create(Camera, TweenInfo.new(AIM_DURR_TIME), {FieldOfView = AIM_FOV})
local tweenOut = TweenService:Create(Camera, TweenInfo.new(AIM_DURR_TIME), {FieldOfView = DEF_FOV})

-- TODO: Fix bug when player changes camera mode in menu
wait(1)
Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable -- Used for creating custom behavior
UserInputService.MouseBehavior = Enum.MouseBehavior.LockCenter -- Lock the cursor
PlayerMouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://9095360160" -- Set dot crosshair

UserInputService.InputChanged:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseMovement then
        xAngle = xAngle - input.Delta.x * 0.4
        yAngle = math.clamp(yAngle - input.Delta.y * 0.4, -80, 80)
    end
end)

-- This will run every frame
runService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    
    local Character = LocalPlayer.Character
    local Root = LocalPlayer.Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    
    if Character and Root then
        
        local startCFrame = CFrame.new((Root.CFrame.p + Vector3.new(0,2,0))) * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(xAngle), 0) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(yAngle), 0, 0)
        local cameraCFrame = startCFrame + startCFrame:vectorToWorldSpace(Vector3.new(cameraOffset.X,cameraOffset.Y,cameraOffset.Z))
        local cameraFocus = startCFrame + startCFrame:vectorToWorldSpace(Vector3.new(cameraOffset.X,cameraOffset.Y,-50000))

        Camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(cameraCFrame.p ,cameraFocus.p)
    end
end)
    
-- Only 'aim' if TOGGLE_MOUSE and TOGGLE_MOUSE are false
PlayerMouse.Button2Down:Connect(function()
    if globals.TOGGLE_MOUSE == false and globals.IS_PLAYER_AIMING == false then
        tweenIn:Play()
        
        globals.IS_PLAYER_AIMING = true
    else
        print("Could not start player aim")
    end
end)

PlayerMouse.Button2Up:Connect(function()
    tweenOut:Play()
    globals.IS_PLAYER_AIMING = false
end)
```

Comment: When you say:  "it didn't work so well" do you mean that it was inaccurate, that the code didn't move the gun at all, that the code crashed?

Comment: When i say that: "it didn't work so well", i mean: "I did not work —  and i don't know how angles and Cordinate Frames work".

Comment: Rather than sharing this code as a PasteBin link, could you include the text in your question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the camera CFrame's, Including Camera.LookAt() and Camera.Rotation